# Slack Slash Command - Getting user icon URL with username (PHP)

Tags: php, slack-api

I am new at programming Slash commands in Slack. For one of my commands, I have a username and need to retrieve the user icon URL. I am using PHP to code them.

I was planning on using users.profile.get, since the tutorial [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get) shows that one of the fields returned is the user icon URL.

However, I am trying to find examples on how to make a call to this method and have not found any. Could anybody give me a quick example of the call, including how to send the parameters?

This is how far I got:

```
$slack_profile_url = "https://slack.com/api/users.profile.get";
$fields = urlencode($data);        
$slack_call = curl_init($slack_profile_url);
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_CRLF, true);                                                               
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($slack_call, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",                                                                                
    "Content-Length: " . strlen($fields))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$profile = curl_exec($slack_call);
curl_close($slack_call);
```

I basically have $token and $user_name and need to get the profile picture URL. How do I format $token and $username as $data? Is the call correct?

If anybody recommends doing this a different way, I would appreciate any advice as well.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using node or PHP? The reference saying they "don't have an explicit method to call this endpoint" is in reference to a node library (and the following sentence explicitly shows you a workaround, followed by example code). Node is not PHP

Comment: I am using PHP. It's good to know that was only for node! Would you recommend using users.profile.get to retrieve the user icon URL when having the username? If so, could you give me an example of how to make the call (or a URL that has one)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, that is the correct endpoint to call. Have you already written any code that makes calls to the slack API, or are you hoping to get talked through that?

Comment: I have made the called used in the tutorial (https://api.slack.com/tutorials/your-first-slash-command) and that works fine, but this is a little different since I am not sure how to encode the parameters and handle the different format (the tutorial uses json instead). So, I would just need an example of the array with the parameters (if it's an array) and the actual call.

Comment: Yeah, that's a little different (and they don't do a good job explaining the difference there). The `Web API` and `Incoming Webhook` for slack are two different processes. It's best to start reading about the [Web API here](https://api.slack.com/web#basics)

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I have read that page; I still haven't found any examples on how to make the call. I was trying to add the code here but I can't do it in the comments; I will do it in the original post.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post. For future reference, that IS the right way to update new details and add code. I'll add an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data into the right format to post to Slack is pretty straight forward. There's two options (POST body or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

The query string for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is formatted like a get URL string.

```
https://slack.com/api/users.profile.get?token={token}&user={user}
// Optionally you can add pretty=1 to make it more readable
https://slack.com/api/users.profile.get?token={token}&user={user}&pretty=1
```

Just request that URL and you will retrieve the data.

The POST body format will use a similar code to what you have above.

```
$loc = "https://slack.com/api/users.profile.get";
$POST['token'] = "{token}";
$POST['user'] = "{user}";

$ch = curl_init($loc);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     

$result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($error = curl_errno($ch)) { echo $error; }

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! However, I am getting a {"ok":false,"error":"invalid_auth"} error, which the documentation suggests is due a to an incorrect token. I checked the token and it matches the one I am given when creating the slash command; isn't that what I am supposed to use here? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! I figured out about the token. If somebody is trying to use something similar, you can't use your slack command token; you need to authorize an app for your team with the permissions/scope you want and then get the token from there. Here is the information: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth